# How to set different exchange correlational functionals in VASP?

Tags: vasp, exchange-correlation

I want to test different exchange correlational functional on Magnesium silicide to investigate the electronic properties. For example, if I have the `POTCAR` library for various pseudopotentials of Mg and Si where we can specify the type of functional from the title/header let's say PBE. How can I change this PBE to PW91 in INCAR to see the effect? The following screencast is my `INCAR` for structure relaxation.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please don't add additional questions as new answers. If it is a minor addition, you can edit it into the original question. For larger changes, generally you should create a brand new question.

Comment: @Shalini can you please copy and paste the INCAR into a `code` block rather than posting a screenshot? This way it's *searchable* and does not take so long to load on people's computers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I change this PBE to PW91 in INCAR to see the effect?

- According to the element order of your `POSCAR`, concatenate the different `POTCAR`s in the GGA pseudopotentials library to generate the final `POTCAR`.
- Set the GGA tag in `INCAR` (All other tags in your screencast is OK to me.):

  - PBE (default):

    ```
    GGA=PE
    ```
  - PW91

    ```
    GGA=91
    ```
  - PBEsol:

    ```
    GGA=PS
    ```

More settings can refer to this link: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/GGA

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Could you please check attached INCAR and give feedback which I understood that just change the value in GGA tag according to different functionals .

Comment: @Shalini It's OK to me.

Comment: @Jack should the follow-up be a separate question? Anyway here is the link to the user's screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkHhn.png, the answer will be deleted.

Comment: @NikeDattani It's not necessary. His question is not well organized.

Comment: @NikeDattani I have re-organized the question post.